# I have a mockup, what's the best WPF control to make this work?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am new to working in C# and WPF

I have a mockup here and I am not sure the best way to go about to design it in XAML/C#.
[image]

(the image was made in a vector program)

I know there is listview and listbox among other grid controls that I could use.
I don't know what to use.

I want the rows and columns to have the visible lines (2px), It has to have a vertical scrollbar. Since the list will have items added during runtime, it has to have a format  for how things are added.
Also I want to use the checkbox for selection rather then a blue highlight. Is this easily done?

Any guidance or suggestions appreciated

Comment: You can use any of them. If you allow user change data you should use DataGrid, For the checkbox you can add a style for it, trigger when a row is selected.

Comment: Well the user will click a button "add" to add a new item. It doesn't have to be directly editable.

Answer (score 1):

Simple DataGrid is the way to go.

You can build upon this :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGrid2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.VerticalGridLinesBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
    </DataGrid.VerticalGridLinesBrush>
    <DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
    </DataGrid.HorizontalGridLinesBrush>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="#">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SNo}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding F1}" BorderThickness="0 0 1 0" BorderBrush="Red" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding F2}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Field1}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```